# showing values or percentages with chartjs in react

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I'm creating a pie chart in a react project with chartjs. But I'm not able to show any values on the different segments. I've tried different plugins but all of them aren't supported anymore.

I'm open to any ideas. That's how I'm rendering the chart at the moment:

```
<Pie
  data={chartData}
  options={{
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                color: "white",
                font : {
                size: 16
            },
        }
      }
      },
    }}
/>
```

Comment: In order to help you better, it would be desirable to know if you're using chartjs in react or if you're using the react-chartjs npm package, or anything similar.

Comment: im using the npm package :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the beta of the datalabels plugin by installing it like this:

```
YARN:
yarn add chartjs-plugin-datalabels@next

NPM:
npm i chartjs-plugin-datalabels@next
```

Live example with chart.js v3:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

var options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['orange', 'blue', 'gray'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3],
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: ['orange', 'blue', 'gray']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        backgroundColor: function(context) {
          return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
        },
        borderColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 25,
        borderWidth: 3,
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        padding: 6,


      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: im new to all of this. I have tried to register the plugin but failed to do so. By now i only imported from "react-chartjs-2". When i try to import from "chartjs" it says that it got no default export. So im not able to register the plugin properly. Hence it doesnt work. Thanks  for the help

Comment: Here is a react sample for the zoom plugin, it shows you how to register it, if you do it in the same way it will work: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chart-js-forked-cn6wh?file=/src/components/Chart.js

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot. Took me wy to long thou :D

Answer (score 0):

The idea that LeeLenalee gave you is correct, but you would need to tweak it a bit to adapt it to your React implementation. You will still need [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-datalabels) library, but you need to register this plugin in the Chart base object.

So, summarizing:

1. You need to install three libraries `npm install --save chart.js react-chartjs-2 chartjs-plugin-datalabels` if you don't have them yet
2. Import the following where you are implementing your chart

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLables from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

3. Manually registering the plugin. This is the key to get the labels working: `Chart.register(ChartDataLables);`
4. Now you can add the datalabels configs into the plugin props, which will show the values inside the chart

```
datalabels: {
  display: true,
},
```

After these stpes, your Pie chart implementation should look similar to this. I wrapped it into a new component just to be able to reuse it if needed.

```
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLables from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
import { Pie } from 'react-chartjs-2';

Chart.register(ChartDataLables);

export const UsagePieChart = ({ chartData }) => {
  return (
    <Pie
      data={chartData}
      options={{
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              color: 'white',
              font: {
                size: 16,
              },
            },
          },
          datalabels: {
            display: true,
            color: 'white',
            font: {
              weight: 'bold',
            },
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```